# MPAndroidChart data from slqlite is not showing in the Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to populate a [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) using sqlite data, all seems to work but I dont know why chart itself is not showing in the activity. 
Sqlite query have data like this in it:

```
----------------------
| Data       | Usage |
|------------|-------|
| 2016-04-24 | 7.58  |
| 2016-04-06 | 7.74  |
| 2016-03-13 | 8.46  |
| 2016-03-22 | 8.29  |
----------------------
```

But even so chart is not showing up. I was fallowing the guidie in MPAndroidChart github page, but seems I messed up somethink...

ChartActivity.java

```
public void setData(String car_id){

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

    Cursor curChartFuelUsage = dbHelper.getChartFuelUsage(car_id);
    curChartFuelUsage.moveToFirst();

    int count = curChartFuelUsage.getCount();
    Float[] x_refuel_data = new Float[count];
    Float[] y_fuel_usage = new Float[count];


    if (curChartFuelUsage.moveToFirst()){
        Log.e("CHART", "moveToFirst OK, count: " + count);

            for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
                x_refuel_data[i] = curChartFuelUsage.getFloat(0);
                y_fuel_usage[i] = curChartFuelUsage.getFloat(1);
                curChartFuelUsage.moveToNext();
            }

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
            values.add(new Entry(x_refuel_data[i], y_fuel_usage[i])); 
        }

        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values,"Test");
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
        chart.setData(lineData);
        chart.invalidate();
    }
```

chart_activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    <!--android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.asd.app.ChartActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/chart_activity_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/line_chart_fuel_usage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
It worked after change layout orientatnion to vertical but I dont know why chart only shows values in one line.

[Char pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnHnV.png)

Comment: call chart.invalidate() to start drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent `LinearLayout`'s orientation is set to horizontal, and the AppBarLayout's width is `match_parent`, so there's no more space to draw the chart.

Try changing the parent orientation to `vertical`.

**EDIT**

For your 2nd issue:

Seems your date got transofmed into float (2016.0) and your data happen to have the same prefix (2016-0...).

What you could do is put all your x-axis values in `String[]` and when inserting entry do it like: `values.add(new Entry(i, y_fuel_usage[i]));`

then Use `IAxisValueFormatter` override the Xaxis values:

```
IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return yourStringArray[(int)value];
        }
    };
```

set to XAxis:

```
yourChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Although I haven't tested this particular code above, I used similar one in the past and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks it worked finally! But I have another problem, it only shows values in one line, edited my post.